# Linking against Boost.MPI and Boost.Serilaization in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu

I have ubuntu with boost, boost.MPI installed. I don't know how can I link against Boost_MPI and Boost_Serialization though. For commands like this,

> mpic++ -I/path/to/boost/mpi my_application.cpp -lboost_mpi-gcc-mt-1_35 -lboost_serialization-gcc-d-1_35.a

how can I know the appropriate names of the libraries ?
Tarek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following steps:

1. Use synaptic package manager and make sure that *libboost-serialization-dev* and *libboost-mpi-dev* are installed.
2. Try lib names without version number.

   mpic++ my_application.cpp -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization

If it doesn't work go back to the package manager, select the library and click *Properties* button. From there you can see full path name for the selected package's install files.